# Mysql - orderby count of another statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order list of friends of the current user by count of unread messages from friends. More unread messagesa friend has towards current user, higher he should be placed in the list.

I managed to put together a query that returns count of unread msgs for current user from specific user id.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS unread_msg
FROM messages m LEFT JOIN users u ON m.from_user_id = u.id
    WHERE 1 /* Current user, unread msg to */ IN (from_user_id,to_user_id)
      AND 2 /* Friend, unread msg from */ IN (from_user_id,to_user_id)
      AND to_user_id = 1 /* Current user, unread msg to */
      AND seen = 0
```

And with the help of SO-sql gurus I've a query for friends list:

```
SELECT a.name_surname,
       a.avatar,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS friend_words,
       (a.friend_id) AS friend_msg_id /* Unread msg from id */
FROM (
  SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
       f1.created,
       u.name_surname,
       u.avatar
  FROM friends AS f1 
  INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
       AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
  WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
       AND f1.asker_user_id = 1 /* Current user id */
) a
LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
GROUP BY 1
```

Any ideas how to unite these queries? So I get unread_msg inside second query?

and the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/129a6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

I just took your second query, nested it and added a left join with the messages table and the appropriate grouping.

I believe it could be constructed more efficiently (without extra nesting) but I'm a bit worried of how it would perform with the GROUP_CONCAT you have there (plus I'm not sure what the words table does), and there was not enough data in your tables to test it.

```
select b.name_surname,b.avatar,b.friend_words,b.friend_msg_id, count(m.id) from (
    SELECT a.name_surname as name_surname,
           a.avatar as avatar,
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS friend_words,
           (a.friend_id) AS friend_msg_id /* Unread msg from id */
    FROM (
      SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
           f1.created,
           u.name_surname,
           u.avatar
      FROM friends AS f1 
      INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
           AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
      WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
           AND f1.asker_user_id = 1 /* Current user id */
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
    LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
) b
left join messages m on m.to_user_id = 1 
          and m.from_user_id = b.friend_msg_id 
          and m.seen = 0
group by b.name_surname,b.avatar,b.friend_words,b.friend_msg_id
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, this returns 0 new msgs. I actually had to add in GROUP BY 1 before ) b - otherwise it was returning only 1 friend. In my test db user has two friends and friends can have no words and must be displayed anyways, so group 1 helps that.

Comment: when I copy pasted your solution it worked... before I simply copied nesting container part... DId you change something within my query also? I can't seem to notice difference :S

Comment: Well, I tested it out, and it works perfectly! 1 thing though, how do I order results by count(m.id)

Comment: Hi, I didn't change anything in your old query (nested), I just added some aliases in the first two columns (`as name_surname` & `as avatar`) and I deleted the `group 1` clause (I think it's no use but I may be wrong). you can just add `order by count(m.id) desc` or(`asc`) at the end of the query. Glad to help